# Laravel 8 Display Data in View and Sent Data to Database

Tags: javascript, php, html, database, laravel

First of all, I'm a beginner in programming world. Just learn to print hello world this early January.

For this project, I’m using Laravel 8.

I have 4 table in database. The first one is **forms**, second is **cats**, **catdetails** is the third one and lastly is **cat_catdetails**. The attributes for each table is below:

[image: Tables Attributes]

The cats table is set to have this data (fixed):

[image: cats table]

**cats** and **catdetails** relationship is many-to-many, so I use **cat_catdetails** as a join table and the relationship is one to many between “**cats** and **cat_catdetails**” and “**catdetails** and **cat_catdetails**”

Basically the goal I want to achieve is something like this

cat_catdetails table:

[image: cat_catdetails tables]

In views, I create something like this

[image: View]

When the checkbox is checked, user can enter the detail (This code is done).

This is what I can make so far:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
   <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
     <tr>
       <th >Cat</th>
       <th >Age</th>
       <th >Weight</th>
       <th >Height</th>
     </tr>

     @foreach($cats as $cat)
     <tr>
       <th scope="row">
        <input type="checkbox" id="name" name="name" value="{{$cat->id}}"/>{{$cat->name}}
       </th>
        <td><input type="number" id="age" name="age" value="" disabled /></td>
        <td><input type="number" id="weight" name="weight" value="" disabled /></td>
        <td><input type="number" id="height" name="height" value="" disabled /></td>
     </tr>
     @endforeach
   </table>
 </div>
</div>
```

**Question:**

1. How to configure the controller for this project ?
2. How to display this in view using @foreach and assign each input id ?
3. Are my database and table flow is accceptable ? Are there any simple way to do ?

Sorry if my question is very stupid. I really hope some expert can guide me for this project.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to look on how to handle your databases. see this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships) so you can see how things works in your relational modeling.

I don't know if you're really onto doing **Many to Many** relationship because your **database model** says so but your **Interface** don't match with your **database model**. It feels like `cat` has many `cat_datails` on the **Interface**.

#### You also need to learn frontend frameworks

What you want to do with the **Interface** is hard to do with full `PHP` or `Laravel`. You can use alternative frontend framework like `ajax`, [vue js](https://vuejs.org/), [livewire](https://laravel-livewire.com/), or other frontend framework.

You can also check this [tallstack](https://tallstack.dev/). This stack is use to ease the workflow of laravel project.

#### You make check this tutorial

You can check this out, maybe you can learn something from them.

[Laracast](https://laracasts.com/) some of the basic are here and also other videos are free.

[Coders Tape](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCQI-Ym2rLZx52vEoqlPQMdg) He can explain the basic very well.

Hope this will help you on your problem

Comment: Thank You for the link. My situation is, each user can open a form.. In 1 form, there are many section.. One of that section is catdetails section (catdetails table). 1 form has ID, and that ID will connect to catdetails table(form and catdetail has one-to-one relay). In catdetail, there may be many id from the cat table. For the interface shown above, that is part of a form.

Comment: I think what you need is [hasManyThrough](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) method. This will allow you to get the cats using the form only and can also query through the table